# Radical extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose we have
$$
K \subset K(a_1) \subset K(a_1, a_2) \subset K(a_1, a_2, a_3)
$$
such that $a_j^{p_j}\in K_{j-1}$: a radical extension in other words.

I am having trouble understanding why for example the extension $K(a_1, a_2):K(a_1)$ need not be radical. The criteria "$a_j^{p_j}\in K_{j-1}$" still holds over this extension right? So then, how come intermediate extensions need not be radical?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think that the chain of subfields that you've described isn't radical?

> **Definition.** A finite extension $L/K$ is **radical** if you can find a finite chain of subfields $K=L_0\subset L_1\subset\cdots\subset L_n=L$ such that $L_i=L_{i-1}(a_i)$, and $a_i^{p_i}\in K_{i-1}$, for some $p_i>1$.

Let $K_1=K(a_1)$. Then you're saying that the extension $K_1(a_2)/K_1$, where $a_2^{p_2}\in K_1$, for some $p_2>1$, need not be radical? It certainly seems to satisfy the definition.

Comment: it seems perfectly reasonable to me as well, but Stewart's "Galois Theory" says that if M:K is radical and L is an intermediate field, L:K need not be radical. But if everyone one of the fields is just an extension by 1 element, i don't see how this wouldn't be radical

Comment: @Geano If $M:K$ is radical and $L$ is an intermediate subfield, then $L:K$ needn't be radical, but $M:L$ certainly is.

Comment: @Geano Intermediate extensions of $L/K$ can arise in more ways than just the tower you describe. Fields of the form $K(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ are **not** the only intermediate fields. If $L/K$ is radical, and $K\subset M\subset L$, then $M/K$ need not be radical.

Comment: @egreg but, L:K was achieved by adjoining one element at each step s.t. that element raised to some power is in the field prior. This is by definition, a radical extension, is it not?

Comment: at least this is the way my text defines a radical extension

Comment: @Geano Again, not **every** intermediate extension is formed this way. The one you described is radical because of the way you constructed it, but if you take an arbitrary intermediate field, you cannot guarantee that you can construct it in such a way. This is the point that is being made in Ian Stewart's book. You cannot guarantee that every intermediate field is radical.

Comment: I think Geano is (or was) under the impression that intermediate fields necessarily come in a tower.  Between K and M there will be a tower of intermediate fields showing how M was built as a radical extension of K, and all of *these* intermediate fields will also be radical extensions of K (and of each other).  But there may, as Warren says, be lots of other intermediate fields, and there's no reason to think that they will be radical extensions of K.

Comment: ah i think i got it tell me if this example is correct: say we have Q(a,b) = Q(c). Then if we consider Q(c):Q st c^n is in Q this is radical, but if we now consider Q(a):Q, it might be the case that no power of a is in Q.

Comment: Perhaps OP would find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739995/if-k-mathrmgal-f-is-obtained-by-adjoining-nth-roots-must-k-f-be-as-w/780837#780837 helpful.